# How do I generate media files with names that contain blanks?

Tags: install4j

I have this in my `.install4j` file:

```
  <mediaSets>
    <windows ...
    mediaFileName="${compiler:product.name} ${compiler:edition.name} Win32 ${compiler:sys.version}" ...>
  <mediaSets>
```

The issue is with the name of the generated media file.
I get: `Our-Product_Enterprise_Win32_6.0.36-SNAPSHOT.exe`
I want: `Our-Product Enterprise Win32 6.0.36-SNAPSHOT.exe`

I switched off the "Convert dots to underscores" setting, which helped clean up the version number, but how do I prevent Install4J from replacing all blanks with underscores?

I could live with using some other character, but:
`_` (underscore) is confusing since the name already has dashes in it (it should be possible to read out a name over the telephone).
`-` (dash) is even more confusing since there are more dashes in it.
`~` (tilde) looks weird - the installer is seen by non-tech people, and I don't want to confuse them.
en-space and em-space might work, but could cause character set weirdness, particularly since we're building Linux and Windows installers (and maybe Mac installers in the future). I.e. I'll want to stick with ASCII-7 if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. For 8.0.3, I have now implemented an option "Convert spaces to underscores" so you can disable the replacement.

Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.

Comment: Heh. We'll have to upgrade to 8 then I guess. (That's a new license if you're on 7, right?) Or maybe add a Maven step that renames the files.

Comment: You don't have to purchase a new license, there is an upgrade product for older versions and you can ask us at support@ej-technologies if you are eligible for a free upgrade.

Comment: Ah thanks. We'll pursue that route as soon as we get around to upgrading the license server, which I understand is necessary to upgrade Install4J to 8.